# Are shared memory segments compatible across boost versions and compiler versions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, ipc, shared-memory

I'm maintaining an old project, and now it has to work with another project build with a newer version of visual studio and a newer version of boost. To communicate with other processes, the first project uses a shared memory segment, so now the second project has to read this segment (and write to it) but not create it.

Is this possible? are there any restrictions? I don't seem to find any documentation about it.

Boost versions involved: 1.35 and 1.55 (it might be updated to 1.56)
Visual Studio versions: 8.0 and 2013.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question.

On the library level, I'd  assume that no breaking changes exist unless they were document.

However, there are many more things to take into account.

1. You Are Sharing Memory

   This implies you're directly sharing memory representations of your classes.

   This implies:

*Implies:*

2. You Are Sharing ABI

   This already rules out compatibility even if you happen to use slightly different compiler flags, with **the same compiler/library** versions.

In other words, don't share memory unless you control both ends and can make sure they are binary compatible.

#### SUMMARY

Boost's shared memory offerings say **nothing** about data representation (beyond "if you can link it into the same binary, it's good enough for IPC access"). So, if you need this level of isolation, look at

- Boost Serialization
- combine with [EOS Portable Archives](http://epa.codeplex.com/) for bigger portability